# Cannot login into PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner to using Laradock. I have started up my MySQL container, and I am trying to figure out the Server, Username, and Password to use when i go to localhost:8080.

[image]

I looked in the laradock env file:

```
MYSQL_VERSION=latest
MYSQL_DATABASE=default
MYSQL_USER=default
MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
```

However when I use these as username and passwords, it does not do the trick.

Could someone help me with this? I am not sure exactly what I am supposed to be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the default username and password in phpMyadmin is "root" each, and then your `.env` file should match that (or whatever the credentials are in phpMyadmin in your case) not the other way around..

Comment: The default username and password for the root MySQL user are root and root.  Source:  https://laradock.io/documentation/

Comment: So should I change the username and password in the laradock.env file to root and root then save it? Just tried that and I am not sure if that worked. Is the servername supposed to be localhost?